# Two Actions For One Web Form

Tags: wordpress, forms, sendmail

I've a simple web form which upon Submit, sends data to vTiger Leads. Form has an action `http://IP/crm/path/capture.php`

However, I also want this form to send an email too.

I'm not able to understand how sendmail can be combined with this one action. I cannot have two separate buttons for the form.

- Will I need to create a separate php file to include these two functions? If yes, how?
- Or can it be done using JS ?
- I'm using WordPress - so is there any way we recreate this form & add two actions?

Any lead would be very helpful. TIA

Comment: Are you aware of this plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-leads-builder-any-crm/

Comment: Last time I tried but it didn't connect to my CRM. I'm going to give it a try again. Will update again